# ClassName<Type.GetType("Somenamespace.ClassName")>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Basically what I need is to use the Type that i got using Type.GetType in a Generic Type,
is it possible, if yes how ?
I need something like this:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("mynamespce.a.b.c");
var x = GenericClass<t>();
```

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326285/deciding-on-type-in-the-runtime-and-applying-it-in-generic-type-how-can-i-do-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Type.MakeGenericType and Activator.CreateInstance to make an instance of the generic type, e.g.

```
Type t = Type.GetType("mynamespce.a.b.c");
Type g = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(t);
object x = Activator.CreateInstance(g);
```

But it won't be strongly typed as the type of generic class in your code, if that's what you're looking for. That isn't possible as C# doesn't allow you to work with open generic types.

Comment: too bad I wanted to use it for IoC.Resolve(g)

Comment: :) it actually worked, I did managed to do Ioc.Resolve(g), also got the method by reflection, and invoked it :)

Comment: You call your method like this: GenericClass<t>();
In the method you cast to type of t: 
t x = Activator.CreateInstance(g) as t; 

(code is not tested)

Answer (score 3):

It can be done: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx (See section *"Constructing an Instance of a Generic Type"*)

The following example creates a `Dictionary<string,object>`:

```
Type d1 = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
Type[] typeArgs = {typeof(string), typeof(object)};
Type constructed = d1.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type t = Type.GetType("mynamespce.a.b.c");
Type gt = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(t);
var x = Activator.CreateInstance(gt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, but you will have to use further reflection. And you get the resulting object as a System.Object.

```
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(Type.GetType("mynamespce.a.b.c")));
```