# Instantiate class with generic type list and determine the concrete type dynamically

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I have a class with generic type list, but I need to instantiate the class and based on certain value determine the concrete type for the list.

Class looks as follows:

```
public class RestResponse<TData>
{
    public List<TData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I tried following but I guess this is not the right approach:

```
var **genericRestTypeObj** = typeof(RestResponse<>);
switch(concreteTypeVal)
{ 
    case "1": {
        Type restObjType = typeof(apiModel);
        Type makeRestType = genericLogTypeObj.MakeGenericType(restObjType);
        var restObj = Activator.CreateInstance(makeRestType);
        **genericRestTypeObj** = restObj as GiTSLogApiOutputModel<AdminActionLogApiModel>;

        break;
    }
    case "2": {.....}
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not really following what you're asking.  Are you looking for some sort of factory?

Comment: If you are implementing code based on a generic type being specific types then you have misunderstood the purpose of generics and are doing it wrong. Generics are, well generic, ie the same code should work for every value type used with that generic class/method etc.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I think yes.

Comment: @David Can you please elaborate further or point me to some material?

Comment: Ok so if I understand this correctly, you want to create a `new List<T>()` where the Type `T` is determined by some `switch` statement?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes! Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @kinjaldave, you are replicating method overloading through generics. Just use method overloading.

Comment: @kinjaldave along the lines of what David was saying, that kinda defeats the purpose of generics (which is _compile time_ type safety).  You might want to look at [Is it impossible to use Generics dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234008/is-it-impossible-to-use-generics-dynamically)

Comment: Thank you @David and ryanyuyu for your responses. I understand the compile time safety check with generics here. In that case what should I be doing given the scenario in the code I mentioned in my original question? Please suggest.